# integrate Digital handwriting in Android?

Tags: android, digital-handwritting

I am working on **NotePad app** in which I have to prepare notes when I am in meeting.

For users simplicity, I want to include **digital handwriting function** in the application. I have done research in which I found [WRITE PAD](http://www.phatware.com/index.php?q=page/writepad/ipad#) as an app which works in Android.

But I am getting the SDK with which I can implement this functionality in my application.

Please suggest m.

**ADDED**:

Also I found that, the digital handwriting tool is provided in my Samsung Galaxy device as a Google Keyboard but it is not provided in my Moto G device. So that why I have to implement this as an internal functionality in the app.

Comment: I'd suggest you look at the Android gestures api. Gestures are not the same as handwriting, but then handwriting with a finger on an Android device (or even an iPad) is quite difficult. If I were you, I'd try supporting only devices with pen-like functionality. A pen gives you pressure sensitivity, more precision than a finger, and the ability to ignore touch inputs not made by the pen (therefore it allows you to rest your hand on the device while you're writing, or use your finger as an eraser while the pen acts as a pen). Both Samsung and HTC have devices with penlike functionality

Comment: There is also a general Android pen api starting in Android 3.1 (I think), so we're likely to get many more manufacturers supporting pen-like functionality than those two.